# Build XML of Images

Tags: xml, macos, image, publish

I am trying to find something easy to make an XML of images and possibly publish them to my webserver.  I have Mac OS X Lion.  I usually use Podcast Maker for making podcasts, but it doesn't support images.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why an XML of images?
Just put the images on your ftp for example and link the exact url to the image in your xml.
Think this will work better.